# Are all C/C++ Hunspell APIs thread-unsafe?

Tags: c++, spell-checking, aspell, hunspell

Are all C/C++ APIs for example `spell()`, `suggest()`; `analyse()` in the Hunspell library  thread-unsafe?

When I use the `suggest()` API with a lock, I see on an average 50-100 requests for suggestion processed in a second? Did any one try to do benchmarks on this?

Any suggestion for improvement is welcome (including any commercial options for Spell Check and corrections, our web-application is based on C++.)

Comment: I don't know about threads, but to our experience, hunspell is just slow when comes to generating suggestions. The speed we see (when called from Java) is documented at http://wiki.languagetool.org/hunspell-support: 57 sentences/second, 770 sentences/second when not generating suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i saw in my tests  around 50 single word suggestions per second. With increase in number of threads with multiple instances of hunspell my I7 CPU maxed out.

Comment: @s.s So you managed to use Hunspell in multiple threads without locking? Because locking effectively makes it kinda single threaded.